# Error message displayed when creating a new user after a successful purchase in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

```
function action_woocommerce_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    // Determines whether the current visitor is a logged in user.
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return;
    
    // Get $order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    // Get the user email from the order
    $order_email = $order->get_billing_email();

    // Check if there are any users with the billing email as user or email
    $email = email_exists( $order_email );  
    $user = username_exists( $order_email );

    // If the UID is null, then it's a guest checkout (new user)
    if ( $user == false && $email == false ) {
        // Random password with 12 chars
        $random_password = wp_generate_password();
        
        // Firstname
        $first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
        
        // Lastname
        $last_name = $order->get_billing_last_name();
        
        // Role
        $role = 'customer';

        // Create new user with email as username, newly created password and userrole          
        $user_id = wp_insert_user(
            array(
                'user_email' => $order_email,
                'user_login' => $order_email,
                'user_pass'  => $random_password,
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name'  => $last_name,
                'role'       => $role,
            )
        );
        
        // Get all WooCommerce emails Objects from WC_Emails Object instance
        $emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

        // Send WooCommerce "Customer New Account" email notification with the password
        $emails['WC_Email_Customer_New_Account']->trigger( $user_id, $random_password, true );

        // (Optional) WC guest customer identification
        //update_user_meta( $user_id, 'guest', 'yes' );

        // User's billing data
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1', $order->get_billing_address_1() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_2', $order->get_billing_address_2() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', $order->get_billing_city() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_company', $order->get_billing_company() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_country', $order->get_billing_country() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email', $order_email );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', $order->get_billing_first_name() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name',  $order->get_billing_last_name() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $order->get_billing_phone() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', $order->get_billing_postcode() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_state', $order->get_billing_state() );

        // User's shipping data
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_1', $order->get_shipping_address_1() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_2', $order->get_shipping_address_2() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_city', $order->get_shipping_city() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_company', $order->get_shipping_company() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_country', $order->get_shipping_country() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_first_name', $order->get_shipping_first_name() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_last_name', $order->get_shipping_last_name() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_method', $order->get_shipping_method() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_postcode', $order->get_shipping_postcode() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_state', $order->get_shipping_state() );

        // Link past orders to this newly created customer
        wc_update_new_customer_past_orders( $user_id );
        
        // Auto login
        wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
    }  
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1 );
```

I am using the latest versions of WooCommerce and WordPress with the above source code on my site. For a purchase, the customer only needs to enter an email address (required), name (optional), lastname (optional), notes or additional explanations (optional), and if the payment method is by check, a phone number input option is also displayed (required). I have deleted the other options(input example address, country and...). Now, the problem is that after a successful purchase, the customer encounters an error. I have written the list of errors below. However, when I delete the above code, the problem is also resolved and the successful purchase page is displayed completely without errors.

I am using multiple separate files inside function.php, so I cannot accurately find the line that is causing the error. However, with the deletion of this source code, the problem and error are not displayed.

```
Warning: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to int in /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5424

Notice: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to int in /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 33

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/src/vary.cls.php:494 Stack trace: #0 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/src/vary.cls.php(409): LiteSpeed\Vary->finalize_default_vary() #1 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/src/vary.cls.php(312): LiteSpeed\Vary->_update_default_vary() #2 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(326): LiteSpeed\Vary->add_logged_in() #3 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #4 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action() #5 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php(1071): do_action() #6 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/themes/sampletest-child/template-parts/custom_woocommerce/payment/create_new_user_after_payment_successful.php(112): wp_set_auth_cookie() #7 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): action_woocommerce_thankyou() #8 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #9 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action() #10 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php(82): do_action() #11 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(345): include('/home/sampletest/...') #12 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php(333): wc_get_template() #13 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php(63): WC_Shortcode_Checkout::order_received() #14 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php(72): WC_Shortcode_Checkout::output() #15 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php(95): WC_Shortcodes::shortcode_wrapper() #16 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(433): WC_Shortcodes::checkout() #17 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag() #18 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(273): preg_replace_callback() #19 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/widget-base.php(431): do_shortcode() #20 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/widgets/text-editor.php(417): Elementor\Widget_Base->parse_text_editor() #21 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php(2297): Elementor\Widget_Text_Editor->render() #22 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/widget-base.php(614): Elementor\Controls_Stack->render_by_mode() #23 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/widget-base.php(755): Elementor\Widget_Base->render_content() #24 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/element-base.php(464): Elementor\Widget_Base->print_content() #25 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/element-base.php(1375): Elementor\Element_Base->print_element() #26 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/element-base.php(464): Elementor\Element_Base->print_content() #27 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/element-base.php(1375): Elementor\Element_Base->print_element() #28 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/element-base.php(464): Elementor\Element_Base->print_content() #29 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/base/document.php(1749): Elementor\Element_Base->print_element() #30 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/base/document.php(1144): Elementor\Core\Base\Document->print_elements() #31 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/frontend.php(1179): Elementor\Core\Base\Document->print_elements_with_wrapper() #32 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/frontend.php(1074): Elementor\Frontend->get_builder_content() #33 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): Elementor\Frontend->apply_builder_in_content() #34 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #35 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php(256): apply_filters() #36 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/themes/sampletest/template-parts/single.php(23): the_content() #37 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/template.php(792): require('/home/sampletest/...') #38 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/template.php(725): load_template() #39 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/general-template.php(206): locate_template() #40 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/themes/sampletest/index.php(21): get_template_part() #41 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('/home/sampletest/...') #42 /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/sampletest/...') #43 /home/sampletest/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/sampletest/...') #44 {main} thrown in /home/sampletest/public_html/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/src/vary.cls.php on line 494
```

Comment: Does it work, after deactivating "litespeed cache" plugin?

Comment: @Jai - Great, thank you very much.

Yes, the problem was with the plugin, and my code was fine. I never thought the problem would be with this plugin!

But I really need to use this plugin. Is there a solution to fix the problem without deleting or disabling the plugin?

I didn't have this problem before the recent updates, because I had tested it. But after a few updates, without any other visible problems, this section was the problem that buyers reported!

Comment: If the buyer hadn't reported it, how would I have known about this kind of error? Is there a solution to handle or identify these kinds of errors (without having to make a test purchase after every purchase or check every single section of a very large site)?

Comment: Are you sure that user is getting created, using function "wp_insert_user"? It seems that WP_Error object is getting returned, instead of user ID, when this function is called. It can be checked, by printing value of $user_id, after this code as follows: var_dump($user_id);, It can be checked, if user is created in admin panel.

Comment: @Jai - Yes, a new user is created and I just tested again and the user ID is displayed `https://sampletest.dev/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=26&wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fusers.php => and var_dump value is => int(26)`

How do I fix this error you mentioned?

What should I do about the plugin error? Will it be fixed?

Comment: According to provided error log, it seems that WP_Error object might be passed as parameter, instead of user ID, in this function wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );, due to which, this error might be there. It can be checked, if this error still occurs, by activating "litespeed cache" plugin, printing $user_id variable before this line of code: wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );, to check, if error is there.

Comment: if ( !is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) { wp_clear_auth_cookie(); wp_set_current_user ( $user_id ); wp_set_auth_cookie ( $user_id ); }, To check error, this code can be used, regarding login functionality.

Comment: It's strange that after I activated the LiteSpeed plugin, the error disappeared! I didn't make any changes to the code!

I followed your instructions and printed the `$user_id` variable before `wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );` and even before `wp_set_current_user ( $user_id );` and both printed the value `int(27)`.

I replaced the code `if ( !is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) { wp_clear_auth_cookie(); wp_set_current_user ( $user_id ); wp_set_auth_cookie ( $user_id ); }` with the previous code, `wp_set_current_user ( $user_id ); wp_set_auth_cookie ( $user_id );`.

Comment: 1. Why did the site not display an error after re-activating the plugin (without changing the source code)?

2. Can I create an exception instead of displaying the error and causing a problem?

3. Was the error only related to the "automatic login" section? Or was it also for the "create user" code?

Comment: It is not sure, what might be the reason for this error. According to provided error logs, probably, the issue is that, when function "wp_insert_user" is called, it returned WP_Error object, instead of user ID. Then, this error object is passed as parameter to function "wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );", due to this, it causes error in plugin "litespeed cache". By using this condition, if ( !is_wp_error( $user_id ) ), it will handle the error part, if it is there.